# jQuery next loop not going back to first child

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops, jquery-selectors

I'm currently trying to loop through sibling elements but can't get the loop to go back to the first sibling.

I'm using the nextOrFirst function as seen [here](http://www.mattvanandel.com/999/jquery-nextorfirst-function-guarantees-a-selection/)

I've replicated what i'm trying to achieve in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgk8B/)

HTML

```
<div id="stories">
  <div class="swapper"><p>number 1</p></div>
  <div class="swapper"><p>number 2</p></div>
  <div class="swapper"><p>number 3</p></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

$.fn.nextOrFirst = function(selector) {
    var next = this.next(selector);
    return (next.length) ? next : this.prevAll(selector).last();
};

setInterval(

    function swap() {

        $(".swapper").each(function() {

            var nextItem = $(this).nextOrFirst();

            $(this).html($(nextItem).html());

            return;

        });

    }, 5000);

});
```

Comment: the code works fine, its selecting the first element when it doesn't find the next, so perfectly `lastOrFirst`, problem is with the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep same code just replace this line

$(this).html($(nextItem).html());

with this

$(this).insertBefore($(nextItem));

Answer (score 4):

Why not just  move last element to the top and than remove last one

```
setInterval(

    function swap() {
        var $container = $("#stories");
        $container.prepend($container.find('.swapper:last').html());// move last to top
        $container.find('.swapper:last').remove(); // remove last
    }, 2000);
```

I guess you trying to reach something like this:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SuddenDeath/pS5nP/)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is working correctly (but perhaps not as you envisaged). In the first iteration of the `.each()` function

- the first element is set to "number 2" (the value of the second element)
- then the second element is set to "number 3" (the value of the third element)
- finally the third element is set to "number 2" which is now the value of the first element

Comment: I thought it was something like this but my brain wasn't up to it this morning. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple way. Instead of setting the HTML properties of the current item to the next item, just use insertAfter like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jgk8B/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $.fn.nextOrFirst = function(selector) {
        var next = this.next(selector);
        return (next.length) ? next : this.prevAll(selector).last();
    };

    setInterval(

        function swap() {

            $(".swapper").each(function() {

                $($(this).nextOrFirst()).insertAfter($(this));

                return;

            });

    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to your method `nextOrFirst()`, but when you call the loop `each`, there is sth. wrong.

At the first time you get the `nextItem`, you change the text of the first element into `number 2`. So you can just get `number 2` when the 3th time you get the first element as `nextItem`, and your html will show:

```
number 2
number 3
number 2
```

That's why your loop can't go back to the first: it's fine to your `nextOrFirst`, but wrong with your `each`.

Thanks,
Edison